# Can't remove currentUser.uid from device

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-authentication

```
Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
```

This call returns a uid no matter if the user exists or not as an authenticated user. I have tried manually removing the user from the Authentication section of the Firebase web portal, and I have tried removing the user in Swift via:

```
Auth.auth().currentUser?.delete(completion: { (error) in

    print(error)
})
```

I then receive this error:

```
Optional(Error Domain=FIRAuthErrorDomain Code=17011 "There is no user record corresponding to this identifier. The user may have been deleted." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=There is no user record corresponding to this identifier. The user may have been deleted., error_name=ERROR_USER_NOT_FOUND})
```

The uid persists even after deleting the app and rebuilding it on the device.

I just need to get the uid cleared when I remove a user, and for the life of me I can't make it happen. I really need to be able to test brand new devices/accounts using the app for the first time, which isn't possible with this persisting uid. What step am I missing here?

If it helps, I'm doing this with anonymous user accounts. Ideally I would be able to register a new anonymous account and see it appear each time I delete it from the device.

Comment: So after you call delete and it fails, the user is not automatically signed out? If so, this is a bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be an Firebase Auth iOS bug. I have filed a bug with Firebase Auth. What you can do, is catch that error (when you try to delete the user) and on detection `signOut` the user so they are not persisted anymore.

Comment: This is the correct answer. I actually tried it shortly after posting as a sort of "there's no way this should work, it doesn't make sense to sign out a deleted user" but low and behold this works. It's definitely a bug, and huge headache at that. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using anonymous user accounts, you're going to get an automatically generated UID that is tied to the current installed instance of your app. You can see in the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/anonymous-auth):

```
let isAnonymous = user!.isAnonymous  // true
let uid = user!.uid
```

AFAIK, you can't log out/delete an anonymous user, because there is no authentication context to remove. Can you solve your issue by checking for both `isAnonymous` and `uid` at the same time, instead of trying to rely on the existence of `uid`?